# What can I safely burn isopropyl gel fuel in?

Tags: fireplace, materials, fire-hazard, fire

I would like to decant isopropyl gel fuel (i.e. Terraflame) into a safe container to burn in my fireplace.

In other words, I would like to create a fire bowl essentially in my indoor fireplace.

What materials would be safe to use? Ceramic? Concrete? EPS?

Thanks!

Some details:
(1) Fake logs exist where you put the cans of gel fuel in. I don’t like how they look.

(2) My fireplace is a working one.

(3) The issue is that I want to burn wood and my spouse would prefer I did not because of indoor air quality. We are compromising with gel fuel.

Comment: Burning wood and indoor air quality is a concern.  A well designed fireplace/clean chimney, dry wood, and a outside source of combustion air can increase air quality.  Concrete and a point heat source sometimes do not mix well.  Ceramics/glass rated above the temperature of the burning gel should work as well as steel.

Comment: how is the terraflame can unsuitable?

Comment: if there is a problem with indoor air quality there may be something wrong with your fireplace.   what type of fireplace is it? photo?